# How to make sure that template type is a number type?

Tags: c++, templates

How can I sure that the type passed to my template function is a numeric type?

Here is my function:

```
template <typename T>
T toStdNumber()
{
  type_info t_info = typeid(T);
  /* ... Converting my class to T if it's numeric type ... */
}
```

I must do this within the 2003 standard, so `<type_traits>` isn't a solution.

Comment: What do you want to do if `T` is _not_ arithmetic? Because the easiest way is to just go ahead and assume `T` is arithmetic.

Comment: exit function (throw exception, return incorect value, etc.).

Comment: Your suggested error handling is a runtime condition; it is possible to detect this at compile-time and cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A static assertion should do the trick:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T toStdNumber()
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Not an arithmetic type");
    // ...
}
```

[See cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) for the taxonomy of types.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't said that I have to use 2003 standart. My bad.

Comment: Isn't that a C++11 type trait? Of course it came from TR1 so it's been around for a while now.

Comment: @MSalters: It's also fairly trivial to write the trait yourself; the static assertion is the real C++11 feature that you want here. Otherwise you need some clumsier workaround (though that's possible, too).

Comment: @anion155: You can define the trait yourself. There's a suggested implementation on the linked website.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have not found a concise solutions for C++03, I decide to use this creepy construction

```
if (
    typeid(T) != typeid(short int) &&
    typeid(T) != typeid(int) &&
    typeid(T) != typeid(long int) &&
    typeid(T) != typeid(long long int) &&
    typeid(T) != typeid(unsigned short int) &&
    typeid(T) != typeid(unsigned int) &&
    typeid(T) != typeid(unsigned long int) &&
    typeid(T) != typeid(unsigned long long int)
  )
  throw bad_typeid();
```

Comment: C++03 didn't have `long long int`

Comment: The TR1 was issued before C++11 and had implementations of this that worked on C++03. Your compiler may have the TR1, or you can look to boost for compile time alternatives to this as well.